# JAVA: My Linkedlist is only printing my head element and nothing else

Tags: java, linked-list

I have written my own linked list and am reading integers from a file into the list and printing them out. However, only the head of my list is printing and nothing else. I've been staring at this code for so long I feel insane, can anyone help?

Method in a separate 'files' class that reads in a file of integers separated by whitespace. This method will take the next integer and add it to my linked list.

```
public void readValues() {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        while(scan.hasNextInt()) {
            Integer someData = scan.nextInt();
            list.addNode(someData);
        }
        list.printList();

    }
```

This method is in my LinkedList class which takes the data sent from my readValues method in my files class.

```
public void addNode(Integer someData) {
        myNode = new LinkedNode(someData,null);
        //initialize node if this is first element
        if (head == null) {
            head = myNode;
            size++;
        }
        else if (myNode.getNext() == null) {
            myNode.setNext(myNode);
            size ++;
        }
        else if (myNode.getNext() != null) {
            while(myNode.getNext() != null) {
                myNode = myNode.getNext();
        }

        myNode.setNext(myNode);
        size++;
        }

    }
```

This method is also in my LinkedList class and successfully prints the head of my list which with my data is the number 40 followed by ---> and then nothing else. It should print ever other integer read in from my file.

```
public void printList() { 
        LinkedNode current = head;
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.print("list is empty");
            return;
        }
        while(current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.getElement());
            System.out.print(" --> ");
            current = current.getNext();
        }

    }
```

LinkedNode class:

```
public class LinkedNode {

    Integer data;
    LinkedNode next;

    public LinkedNode(Integer someData, LinkedNode next) {
        this.data = someData;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public int getElement() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setElement(Integer data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public LinkedNode getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(LinkedNode next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return data + "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a small bug in the if else conditions in your `addNode()` method due to which your data is not getting added in the list.

**Root Cause**

When you add a new node to your list,

*In the first iteration*

The head is currently null and hence the first if conditions becomes true and your first node gets added (That's why you got the data 40).

*In the Subsequent iteration(s)*

your else if condition checks the myNode's next pointer which will always be null (as per the constructor) and thus it's  next pointer points towards itself. The nodes created from here do not become the part of the list as the next pointer of head was never assigned to any of these and these nodes also point to themselves only.

**Solution**

I made a little modification in the if else conditions:

```
public void addNode(Integer someData) {
    LinkedNode myNode = new LinkedNode(someData,null);
    //initialize node if this is first element
    if (head == null) {
        head = myNode;
        size++;
    }
    else if (head.getNext() == null) {
        head.setNext(myNode);
        size ++;
    }
    else if (head.getNext() != null) {
        System.out.println("in second else if");
        LinkedNode n = head;
        while(n.getNext() != null) {
            n = n.getNext();
        }
        n.setNext(myNode);
        size++;
    }

}
```

*PS: Try debugging your code with dry run, it's a great mental exercise and helps in boosting the learning curve significantly too. All the best! :)*

Comment: Super helpful, this fix worked perfectly and my list is printing exactly right now. I tried to mentally run through my code but I think next time I need to use pen and paper and physically write out what is happening. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your addNode() method. Inside the addNode() method you are first creating a new node named mynode. Now when the head is null it sets head to mynode, thats ok. But when the head is not null the mynode is not being added to the list. Thats why only the first element exist and other's are getting lost.

Hope this helps. Let me know if I can help with anything else. Happy coding!